Cant share the screen on ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
I tried updating the WaylandEnable=false in the file - /etc/gdm3/custom.conf but this caused the booting issue, so I reverted that issue.
On Chrome, I'm able to share the tabs of the Chrome but not the entire screen, it just shows the black screen. How should I fix it? Can anyone Help?

Screen sharing issues with Wayland have been fixed in recent versions of Ubuntu. Upgrade to/fresh install Ubuntu 23.10. Also, 24.04 will be released at the end of April, and will be supported for 5 years. You can upgrade to that after the end of April

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.

Also if you're using 18.04.5 as stated; please apply upgrades asap as your details suggest you've not applied security fixes since  mid 2021 as 18.04 was at 18.04.6 when EOSS was reached in 2023.  Keep your system offline.
